# Unable to make protected java.net.http.HttpRequest() accessible: module java.net.http does not "opens java.net.http" to unnamed module @41d477ed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Here is my error :

```
2023-11-07T23:21:13.207+07:00 ERROR 22720 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.net.http.HttpRequest() accessible: module java.net.http does not "opens java.net.http" to unnamed module @41d477ed] with root cause

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.net.http.HttpRequest() accessible: module java.net.http does not "opens java.net.http" to unnamed module @41d477ed
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried congfig the java security but it does not work and have the above error

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
//                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(true))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->  req.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()


                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Here is my HttpRequest filter and my request: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/signup
I  think there is a error when i config the authorizeHttpRequests(req ->  req.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().contains("/api/v1/auth")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader==null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
        assert authHeader != null;
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        //        SecurityContextHolder là nơi SpringSecurity lưu trữ thông tin xác thực.
        //SecuritySecurity sẽ không xác thực cách tạo SecurityContextHolder.
        //Khi nó tìm thấy các giá trị trong SecurityContextHolder, nó giả định rằng người dùng hiện tại là người dùng được xác thực.
        if(userEmail!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            var isTokenValid = tokenRepo.findTokenByToken(jwt).map(token -> !token.isExpired() && token.revoked).orElse(false);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt,userDetails)&& isTokenValid){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
//                authenticationToken.setDetails(
//                        new We
//                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
```

Comment: The code that you shared doesn't seem to be using HttpRequest. Is this the correct code?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the code and add the httprequest

Comment: None of the code seems directly related to the error. Are you using class `java.net.http.HttpRequest` somewhere in your application?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that somewhere in your application it is trying to use the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#%3Cinit%3E()) for class `java.net.http.HttpRequest`. Since that constructor is declared as protected (`protected HttpRequest()`) you can not use directly. Instead you have to use one of the builder methods to construct an HttpRequest instance. For example `HttpRequest.newBuilder()`. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client for examples.